# How to create a responsive article list in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a specific responsive list for a website but am failing miserably. 
I have tried my best to save as much time for you as i could by creating this JSFiddle page template showing my code.

### http://jsfiddle.net/awx4Lwod/8/

```
<span class="jd-news-articles">
<div class="news-article-1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/191x116">
  <div class="news-article-content-text">
    <h2>NEWS HEADER GOES HERE</h2>
    <h3>October 10, 2014</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod accumsan auctor. Curabitur in nisi imperdiet, sodales dui at, mattis nulla.</p>
    <a href="#">...MORE</a> 
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="news-article-2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/191x116">
  <div class="news-article-content-text">
    <h2>NEWS HEADER GOES HERE</h2>
    <h3>October 10, 2014</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod accumsan auctor. Curabitur in nisi imperdiet, sodales dui at, mattis nulla.</p>
    <a href="#">...MORE</a> 
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="news-article-1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/191x116">
  <div class="news-article-content-text">
    <h2>NEWS HEADER GOES HERE</h2>
    <h3>October 10, 2014</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin euismod accumsan auctor. Curabitur in nisi imperdiet, sodales dui at, mattis nulla.</p>
    <a href="#">...MORE</a> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thinking about it now i should have used an `<ul><li>` structure instead.
How would i go about making it so the images stays positioned on the left but as you scale the screen down the images on the left scale down and the text on the right stay in the boundaries within the height of the image? For example no matter the scale of the image the header should be aligned with the top of the image and the more link on the bottom should be aligned to the bottom of the image with the rest of the content in the middle.

Comment: Try bootstrap... that works wonders.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look into Twitter Bootstrap's [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) and [Responsive Image](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)?

Comment: nope i been meaning to study it though. I'll look into it. Could you make an example utilizing it as an answer to help me get started with it?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's documentation is pretty easy to follow: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

It provide's you with a step-by-step process from a blank page to a full-blown responsive design

Comment: I'm really struggling how i can use the information from that page to create what I'm talking about above. Would you be able to create a JSfiddle example of the layout above to help me understand how to use bootstrap for custom content?